# jQuery How To Change the href attribute from a drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a drop down menu that changes a button's href attribute. 
I'm new to jQuery and I've been copying and pasting codes without understanding how it works.

Here's my pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/53es3gLi

Here's The Full Version:
http://pastebin.com/trieK16d

Is there a way to change #btnLink's href value based on the result of the drop down menu? When I use

```
$("#btnLink").attr("href", $('#Link');
```

It replaces my link with [Object %20% Object], but if I replace $('#Link') with a link, it works, but it's a stationary link. It's independent of the drop down menu.

Also can someone help explain the jquery bits in the code, I would like to know how to use it and why is it used. Thanks in advance

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket and you should retrieve the value: `$("#btnLink").attr("href", $('#Link').val());`

Comment: `$("#btnLink").attr("href", $('#Link');` you're missing a closing `)`

Comment: $("#btnLink").attr("href", $('#Link').val());

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val

Comment: Don't add external links, add code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the jQuery object, not the value of the Link field.

```
$("#btnLink").attr("href", $('#Link').val());
```

Comment: Kindly check this: http://jsfiddle.net/8pjt878s/ You should also place the code inside the change listener.

Comment: After checking the jsfiddle, This solution worked, thank-you very much. I see that you placed the $("btnLink") into the $('#File').change(function, which makes sense now that I look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$("#btnLink").attr("href", $('#Link').val());`

Oh, and I missed the last part of your question:

- `$("#btnLink")` is the same as saying "every DOM element whose ID is "#btnlink". It's how we select stuff in jQuery.
- `.attr("href"` means the attribute "href" of the elements we selected before.
- `$('#Link').val()` refers to another set of DOM elements: "everything with a #link ID. In your case it refers to an input field.
- `.val()` returns the value inside said input field.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#Link')` returns the jQuery object and you are setting the value as jQuery object which is coerced to string, so the value `[Object %20% Object]`. To set the value of the textbox to the `href` attribute use `val()` on Link element

```
$("#btnLink").attr("href", $('#Link').val());
//                                    ^^^^^^
```

Comment: I am actually trying to get the href value from the textbox. The textbox shows the links correctly, but I can't change my button's link to what's showing in the text box. I hope I'm explaining this correctly.

Comment: @WebApprentice For this to work, the URL should be present in the textbox

Comment: I added the full code to my description. Do you mean I have to assign an href value to the textbox? Or does it  just have to show within the string? It does show in the string.

Answer (score -2):

$('#Link') returns a jQuery object which is why you are getting the string "[Object %20% Object]" as the value set in the href attribute. If you are trying to set one links href from another links href you could try

```
$("#btnLink").attr("href", $('#Link').attr('href'));
```